# Everytime a new wp multisite is created blank admin screen

Tags: wordpress

Everytime I create a new site in my multisite wordpress installation the wp-admin screen is blank why?

Answer (score 0):

White screens are PHP errors. Try Debug and see what they are. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Change the "display" line to true

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to dump them to the browser as well as log them.